# JBoss AS 7 with project built using JDK 7 fails on deployment

Tags: jboss7.x, java-7

I use JBoss 7.1.1 Final and I'm building my project using JDK 7 in Eclipse Juno (using ant script). On deployment it fails on loading EJBs. I'm using Oracle JDK 1.7.0_05 for MAC OS

Here is stack trace:

> (MSC service thread 1-2) **Failed to define class com.test.ReportManager in Module "deployment.TEST.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:** com/test/ReportManager : **Unsupported major.minor version 51.0**

```
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [classes.jar:1.6.0_33]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631) [classes.jar:1.6.0_33]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615) [classes.jar:1.6.0_33]
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141) [classes.jar:1.6.0_33]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:327) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:391) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:243) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:73) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:517) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:182) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.getEjbClass(BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.java:225)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.deploy(BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.java:97)
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [classes.jar:1.6.0_33]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [classes.jar:1.6.0_33]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) [classes.jar:1.6.0_33]
```

Any ideas what's the cause?

Thanks,
Lukas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have two options.

1. Configure the build to create jdk6 compatible bytecode.
2. Use jdk7 to run your application in jboss.

from the stack trace it looks like you are running jdk6 u33 instead of jdk7 and the bytecode is not compatible

Comment: The default JDK for root was different from user's settings. Thanks!

Comment: Create a new question and link it here and I will reply. :)